# Pandas DataFrame Custom GroupBy function received wrong data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm having data from a time tracking tool. Within such data I'm trying to group the data by day and do some calculation on pauses, start and end time. Therefore I'm applying a custom group function. But somehow the data received in that function is always the one from group 1. It's always `2019-11-04` and never `2019-11-05`. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Input data:

```
    date_at minutes user_id start   end
0   2019-11-04  60  112826  2019-11-04 08:30:00 2019-11-04 09:30:00
1   2019-11-04  60  112826  2019-11-04 09:30:00 2019-11-04 10:30:00
2   2019-11-04  30  112826  2019-11-04 10:30:00 2019-11-04 11:00:00
3   2019-11-04  30  112826  2019-11-04 11:00:00 2019-11-04 11:30:00
4   2019-11-04  30  112826  2019-11-04 11:30:00 2019-11-04 12:00:00
5   2019-11-04  210 112826  2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 16:00:00
6   2019-11-04  60  112826  2019-11-04 16:00:00 2019-11-04 17:00:00
7   2019-11-04  60  112826  2019-11-04 17:00:00 2019-11-04 18:00:00
8   2019-11-05  45  112826  2019-11-05 09:30:00 2019-11-05 10:15:00
9   2019-11-05  45  112826  2019-11-05 10:15:00 2019-11-05 11:00:00
10  2019-11-05  90  112826  2019-11-05 11:00:00 2019-11-05 12:30:00
11  2019-11-05  60  112826  2019-11-05 13:00:00 2019-11-05 14:00:00
12  2019-11-05  30  112826  2019-11-05 14:00:00 2019-11-05 14:30:00
13  2019-11-05  30  112826  2019-11-05 14:30:00 2019-11-05 15:00:00
14  2019-11-05  60  112826  2019-11-05 15:00:00 2019-11-05 16:00:00
15  2019-11-05  150 112826  2019-11-05 16:00:00 2019-11-05 18:30:00
16  2019-11-05  30  112826  2019-11-05 18:30:00 2019-11-05 19:00:00
```

My code:

```
def custom_groupby(data:pd.DataFrame):
    #print (data)
    data.sort_values(by=['start'], inplace=True, ascending=True)    
    times = list(zip(data.start, data.end))
    erroneous = False
    minutes_working = 0
    minutes_paused = 0

    l = len(times)
    day_begin = times[0][0]
    day_end = times[l-1][1]

    for i, (start1, end1) in enumerate(times):
        minutes_working += (end1 - start1).total_seconds() / 60   

        # is there a next entry?
        if i + 1 == l:
            break

        # get next entry
        start2, end2 = times[i+1]
        if start2 < end1:
            # start time of second entry is before end time of first entry
            erroneous = True
        else:
            minutes_paused += (start2 - end1).total_seconds() / 60

    if (day_end - day_begin).total_seconds() / 60 > 6 and minutes_paused == 0:
        # employee hasn't booked pauses but all as working time; 
        # or hasn't done any pause even though he/she is obliged to do so if working >6h
        erroneous = True
        # minimum pause according to Austrian labor law if working >6h
        minutes_paused = 30

    return pd.Series({
        'from':day_begin.strftime("%H:%M"),
        'to':day_end.strftime("%H:%M"),
        'hours_working':minutes_working / 60, 
        'hours_paused':minutes_paused / 60, 
        'error':erroneous})

df_sums = df.groupby(['date_at']).apply(custom_groupby)
df_sums
```

Results:

```
    from    to  hours_working   hours_paused    error
date_at                 
2019-11-04  08:30   18:00   9.0 0.5 False
2019-11-05  08:30   18:00   9.0 0.5 False
```

As you can see the grouped cell values for `2019-11-05` are the same as for `2019-11-04` and if you enable the `print(data)` in the custom function, you'll see that it's always group 1, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by the line

```
data.sort_values(by=['start'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
```

Since `data` is just a view (not a copy) of the original dataframe `df`, sorting with `inplace=True` inside the applied function is likely to cause similar trouble as modifying a list while looping over it. Changing the line to

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['start'], ascending=True)
```

creates a copy. Then the apply works as expected. Alternatively, you could experiment with sorting `df` prior to grouping, to avoid the additional memory use.